# Position function error

Tags: list-manipulation

I recently upgraded from Mathematica 6 to the most recent version.  In my new version the `Position` function returns strange results that were not present in the old version.  An example:

```
testvec = {1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0}
(* {1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0} *)

Position[testvec, Except[0]]
(* {{0}, {1}, {3}, {6}, {}} *)
```

Why has the mysterious `{0}` appeared at the beginning and `{}` at the end?  These spurious additions mess up my earlier code.

Comment: BTW, `Extract[testvec, %]`, where `%` denotes the results of `Position`, shows you what parts matched.

Comment: The result is also `{{0}, {1}, {3}, {6}, {}}` in _v6.0_: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBN1z.png Which version and OS are you in? Can you share a screenshot of the result?

Comment: Just tested in _v5.2_, the result is still `{{0}, {1}, {3}, {6}, {}}`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvF2w.png Are you sure you're in _v5.2_?

Answer (score 11):

The behavior was enhanced in later versions. You need to use in your case

```
Position[testvec, Except[0], {1}, Heads -> False]
```

to match your old version behavior.

The current behavior, in your case, results in the example output because

- Head of $testvec$ meets condition, and head is position 0.
- The nonzero elements match the condition, positions 1,3, and 6.
- The whole list $testvec$ matches the condition, and has no "position".

Answer (score 6):

I looked at the documentation for `Position` in [Mathematica 6](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v6/ref/Position.html) and the corresponding documentation for [Mathematica 12](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v12/ref/Position.html). I was not expecting (based on your description of the output) to find this in the Mathematica 6 docs:

> The default level specification for Position is {0, Infinity}, with
> Heads->True.

but I did. I'm surprised that you're not seeing the same behavior in Mathematica 6 as in Mathematica 12 because `Heads -> True` means that the head of the expression `List`, which is position `{0}`, should be one of the parts that `Position` checks against the pattern. Since `List` is not 0, it should return `{0}` as a position.

This is also in both the Mathematica 12 and the Mathematica 6 documentation:

> A part specification {} returned by Position represents the whole of expr.

Since, according to the first quote, the default level specification is `{0, Infinity}` and level 0 is the whole expression, and the whole expression is not 0, I would expect it to return `{}`.

So I cannot tell you why it didn't work that way in Mathematica 6, I think it should have. As a workaround, you might use the following:

```
Position[testvec, Except[0], {1, Infinity}, Heads -> False]
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the documentation of the built-in [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) in the section Possible issues, Position looks for matches based on patterns, which may not be the same as numerical equality:

```
Position[testvec, n_ /; n != 0]
```

(*{{1}, {3}, {6}}*)